# What is difference between Google Cloud Messaging(GCM) and Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM)?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

What is difference between **Google Cloud Messaging(GCM)** and **Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM)**?

Answer (score 2):

FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) is a improved version of the Google Cloud Messaging API & it have all features of GCM with some additional features also. Google just announced that Google Cloud Messaging is now Firebase Cloud Messaging. 
**Differences between FCM and GCM**
Firebase Cloud Platform **inherits GCM’s core infrastructure** but simplifies the client development. Developers no longer needs to write their own registration or subscription retry logic. Now, you can integrate FCM in your app with just a few lines of code. 
Plus, FCM includes a web console called Firebase Notifications that reminds me of **Parse Push Console**.

Answer (score 1):

**Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)** part of **Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)**. FCM is the new version of GCM under the Firebase brand. It **inherits** GCM’s core infrastructure to make sure we continue to deliver messages reliably on Android, iOS and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

FCM is the new version of GCM, it inherits GCM' core infrastructure.

Here the excerpt from Firebase support FAQ:

> FCM is the new version of GCM under the Firebase brand. It inherits
>   GCM’s core infrastructure, with new SDKs to make Cloud Messaging
>   development easier.
>
> Benefits of upgrading to FCM SDK include:
>
> Simpler client development. You no longer have to write your own
>   registration or subscription retry logic. An out-of-the-box
>   notification solution. You can use Firebase Notifications, a
>   serverless notifications solution with a web console that lets anyone
>   send notifications to target specific audiences based on Firebase
>   Analytics insights. To upgrade from GCM SDKs to FCM SDKs, see the
>   guides for migrating Android and iOS apps.

Read more [Firebase FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#gcm-fcm)